# Restore WhatsApp backup from different phone number but same Gmail account

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

How can I restore my old chats on WhatsApp from a different phone number but the same Gmail account?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after asking the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp keeps its chats on your internal storage in the folder /WhatsApp/Databases. There might be a large number of files, the latest being the one with no date in it (msgstore.db.crypt12, probably).

I'm not sure if the phone number being different matters if you have not enabled WhatsApp's 2FA, and if you have enabled cloud backups to Google Drive as long as you use the same Google Account you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the old phone, you could just copy the entire WhatsApp folder from old phone internal storage to new phone internal storage.

When you install WhatsApp on new phone, during the process, it will ask for restore from backup. Selecting **YES** will automatically find the backup and restore.

If you have it on your Google drive, you could just download it your new phone internal storage before installing WhatsApp and follow the same procedure.

Comment: "*If you have it on your Google drive, you could just download it your new phone internal storage*" the backup is stored in [Google Drive's "Backups" storage](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/backups), which AFAIK is not possible to be downloaded manually.

Answer (score 0):

Only for older versions. It doesn't work like that on newer versions, since they require to previously do a phone number transfer through the settings in order to set the backup encryption key to the new number (as it is associated with the old one).